# When i change the select i receive: 'Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have this material select component:

```
<FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">
    Filial
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    error={touched.filial && Boolean(errors.filial)}
    value={values.filial}
    defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'filial',
      id: 'outlined-filial-native-simple',
    }}
  >
    <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
    <option value={10}>Ten</option>
    <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
    <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

When i change the option selected i receive:

> index.js:1 Warning: Use the defaultValue or value props on instead of
>   setting selected on

I'm using formik to treat my form:

```
const enhanceWithFormik = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: '', password: '', filial: '' }),
  handleSubmit: values => {
    console.log(values)
  },
  isInitialValid: false,
  validateOnChange: true,
  validateOnBlur: true,
  displayName: 'MyForm',
  validationSchema: schema
})
```

When i fill the fields of my form and click in the submit button is printing corretly the value of filial that i select in the form, but is throwing this error in my console.

How i can fix this?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. You could ignore it if you choose. I don't have experience with `formik`, but maybe it's automatically setting a `selected` prop somehow? What I do know is you're setting both a `value` and a `defaultValue`. You should only use one.

Comment: It suggests you pass an item of your `Selectable` array directly rather than set a default label in your options

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing and now I resolved it. I'm not using formik in my project, but the following is similar to my approach and hope it helps.

First, in your `<Select>` tag you have both `value` and `defaultValue`. But just having one of them is fine. (notice the warning you received says "Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props"). In your case, let's say you would remove the `defaultValue` and keep the `value`.

Now, make sure `values.filial` is set as `'DEFAULT'`, so `value={values.filial}` would mean the initial value is `'DEFAULT'`, and the drop down will initially display `Choose a salutation ...`

The handleChange function should then re-render the component as the drop down selection is changed.